# PostgreSQL: Exist all in array

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I have a postgresql array `a = [key1,key2,...]` with primary keys and a table `foo`.

What's the best way to check if **all** the primary keys in `a` exist in the table `foo`?

To clarify: I am looking for a query that returns `TRUE` if and only if all the keys in the array `a` exist in the table `foo`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can count rows from the join of the table and unnested array:

```
select count(*) = array_length(array[1,2], 1)
from foo
join unnest(array[1,2]) id
using (id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Being vague in the question, I am going to assume you have the array in some kind of a programming language and you want to check it against the primary key column of the table.

Look at this example of using the [contains @> operator](http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/228-PostgreSQL-Array-The-ANY-and-Contains-trick.html) (around the middle of the page).

Elaborate in the comments if that is not what you are looking for and please be as specific as you can.

Comment: That is unfortunately not what i meant. The array is a posgresql array.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure this doesn't work with PG arrays. While there is a cast required in the example because the storage type is `VARCHAR`, try `@>` with an array type and see.